# How many times has the original Nine Tails attack been flashed back?

Tags: naruto

After looking at episode 248, I managed to once again gain a nice little view of the Nine Tails attack on Konoha. Even though we get a different point of view each and every time, it still is the original Nine Tails attack... AGAIN.

[image: Kyuubi released in Konoha]

With that said, I've been wondering: How many times have we actually seen the Nine Tails attack the village, or at least fragments of this? And if possible, how much screen time has this taken in the two series so far?

Comment: I doubt Masashi Kishimoto himself can tell you that. +1 though for a very interesting question :D

Comment: would the Openings count? i've seen 3 different openings for just the first Season alone (before the Chunin Exams) and one of them at the start has the 3rd Hokage repeat "12 year ago, the 9-tailed fox suddenly appeared" with the 9 tails appearing before cutting top the music

Comment: @Memor-X although I think it would make for a funny side fact. it is best to just keep it in the series itself excluding the OP/ED's

Comment: in the manga it is limited to 20 or so i think.

Comment: @Sp0T Lies ;) I actually went around all the manga and found out it happens 37 times in there xd.

Comment: well i just guessed. but didn't think that the number of flashbacks in naruto would be this much high... ;)

Comment: @Sp0T Yeah it suprised me a bit aswell. But now i still wonder how many times it happend in the anime series. As it defintly happend even more in there.

Comment: seems like another reason to read and watch the series all over again... :D

Comment: Are movies fair game too?

Comment: @krikara I guess they are yes.

Comment: Lol, you're right XD. I started Naruto a few weeks ago but it's amazing how much they use that clip.

Comment: @Scarletgirl While your at it, count them!! :D  then maybe we will have a answer in the near future ;)

Answer (score 13):

In the anime series? Who knows.

But in the manga:

```
Naruto chapter 1, page 1, 17, 37, 49
Naruto chapter 2, pages 13-14
Naruto chapter 2, page 5    
Naruto chapter 2, pages 14-15
Naruto chapter 500, pages 8-9
Naruto chapter 500, pages 9-10, 12
Naruto chapter 607, pages 6-7
Naruto chapter 500, pages 13-17
Naruto chapter 501, pages 1-6
Naruto chapter 501, page 7
Naruto chapter 501, pages 12-17
Naruto chapter 502, pages 1-6
Naruto chapter 502, pages 7-17
Naruto chapter 503, pages 3-4, 8
Naruto chapter 503, pages 5-7
Naruto chapter 503, page 9
Naruto chapter 503, pages 10-17
Naruto chapter 503, pages 13-19
Naruto chapter 504, pages 1-9
Naruto chapter 504, pages 10-14
Naruto chapter 440, page 15
Naruto chapter 499, page 3
Naruto chapter 440, page 5
Naruto chapter 399, page 15
Naruto chapters 399-401
Naruto chapter 484, pages 8-9
Naruto chapter 485, page 6
Naruto chapter 399, page 16
Naruto chapter 502, page 2
```

**Naruto: Shippūden episode 68**

```
Naruto chapter 149, page 9
Naruto chapter 370, pages 15-16
Naruto chapter 386, page 11
Naruto chapter 399, pages 14-15
Naruto chapter 440, page 10
Naruto chapter 500, page 7
Naruto chapter 597, pages 20-21
```

Comment: hmm I taught 37, seems like I double counted 1 somewhere. Nice list. All tough I am looking for the anime list, this surely is worth a upvote ;)

Comment: May I ask what is your intention when you put **Naruto: Shippūden episode 68** in your answer?